# New Object in a loop is getting overwritten in Java

Tags: java, loops, object, recursion

So I'm trying to create a new object to add to a list

```
public void findWord(char boggle[][], boolean visited[][], int i,
                          int j, String str)
{
    visited[i][j] = true;
    str = str + boggle[i][j];

    if (hasWord(str)) {
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            Position<Character> pos = new Position<>(c, i, j);
            list.add(pos);

        }
    }

    for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1 && row < 4; row++)
        for (int column = j - 1; column <= j + 1 && column < 4; column++)
            if (row >= 0 && column >= 0 && !visited[row][column])
                findWord(boggle, visited, row, column, str);

    visited[i][j] = false;
}
```

The problem is that basicly every Position (row and column) are getting overwritten to the last instance created of this object, but the element itself is not.

My position class:

```
public class Position<T> {

private T element;
private int row;
private int column;

Position () {
    this(null,0,0);
}
Position (T element) {
    this.element = element;
}

Position (T element, int row, int column) {

    this.element = element;
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}

public int getRow() {

    return row;
}

public int getColumn() {

    return column;
}

public T getElement() {

    return element;
}

public String toString() {

    return element + "(" + Integer.toString(row) + "," + column + ")";
}
```

That said, the List output once I print it, is something like :

```
a(2,2) a(2,2) r(2,2) o(2,2) n(2,2)
```

The last position is correct, both in Element and indexes, but all the others fail in the matrix indexing. Should be :

```
a(0,0) a(1,0) r(1,1) o(1,2) n(2,2)
```

The hole class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Boogle {

    LinkedList<Position<Character>> list = new LinkedList<>();

    static QuadHashTable<String> table = new QuadHashTable<>();

    String word;

    static char matrix [] [] = {

        {'a', '-', '-', '-'},
        {'a', 'r', 'o', '-'},
        {'-', '-', 'n', '-'},
        {'-', '-', '-', '-'}
    };

    public Boogle () {

        this(null);
    }

    public Boogle (char matrix [] []) {

        this.matrix = matrix;

    }

    public boolean hasWord (String s) {

        return s.equals(table.search(s));
    }

    public void findWordsUtil(char boggle[][], boolean visited[][], int i,
                              int j, String str)
    {

        visited[i][j] = true;
        str = str + boggle[i][j];

        if (hasWord(str))
            for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
                Position<Character> pos = new Position<>(c, i, j);
                list.add(pos);
            }


        for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1 && row < 4; row++)
            for (int column = j - 1; column <= j + 1 && column < 4; column++)
                if (row >= 0 && col >= 0 && !visited[row][column])
                    findWordsUtil(boggle, visited, row, column, str);
        visited[i][j] = false;
    }

    public LinkedList<Position<Character>> solve () {

        String s = "";

        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[4][4];


        String str = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                findWordsUtil(matrix, visited, i, j, str);



        return list;
    }

    public static void main (String args []) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/dsolipa/Desktop/allWords.txt"));

        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            table.insert(line);
        }

        Boogle boogle = new Boogle(matrix);

        System.out.println(boogle.solve());

        //System.out.println(boogle.hasWord("or"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Define `Position<Character> pos = new Position<>(c, i, j);` outside of your for-each loop.

Comment: I did that aswell same problem. But thanks!

Comment: Please post all code

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Whats missing / doesnt need to be there? Sorry for all the noob questions -_-

Comment: Can you give an example and the expected output?

Comment: So its a game that basicly checks if a word belongs to a HashTable with 58k entries, then on a 4x4 matrix adds the position of each character  to a list.  For instance the word aaron, is suppose to be printing a(0,0) a(1,0) r(1,1) o(1,2) n(2,2). Yet it is printing a(2,2) a(2,2) r(2,2) o(2,2) n(2,2)

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as an answer below. Might help somebody later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the condition `if (hasWord(str))` is passed only when the string is aaron, and your for loop is iterating over the string **str** and adding all the characters at the position of n i.e (2,2). Recheck the implementation in the QuadHashTable class.

Please make the below changes:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

public class Boogle {

    LinkedList<Position<Character>> list = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<Position<Character>> table = new LinkedList<>();
    Map indexMap = new HashMap();
    static QuadHashTable<String> table = new QuadHashTable<>();

    String word;

    static char matrix [] [] = {

        {'a', '-', '-', '-'},
        {'a', 'r', 'o', '-'},
        {'-', '-', 'n', '-'},
        {'-', '-', '-', '-'}
    };

    public Boogle () {

        this(null);
    }

    public Boogle (char matrix [] []) {

        this.matrix = matrix;

    }

    public boolean hasWord(String s) {

        return s.equals(table.search(s));

    }

    public void findWordsUtil(char boggle[][], boolean visited[][], int i,
                              int j, String str)
    {

        visited[i][j] = true;
        str = str + boggle[i][j];


        if (hasWord(str))
        {
            for (char c : str.toCharArray())
            {            
                ArrayList coordinates = (ArrayList)indexMap.get(c);
                String xy = (String)coordinates.get(0);                

                if(coordinates.size() !=1) // or check with flag in visited matrix 
                {
                    coordinates.remove(xy);
                    indexMap.put(c,coordinates);                    
                }

                String [] rowCol = xy.split(":");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[1]);                        

                Position<Character> pos = new Position<>(c, x, y);
                list.add(pos);
            }
            return;


        }


        for (int row = i - 1; row <= i + 1 && row < 4; row++)
            for (int column = j - 1; column <= j + 1 && column < 4; column++)
                if (row >= 0 && column >= 0 && !visited[row][column])
                    findWordsUtil(boggle, visited, row, column, str);
        visited[i][j] = false;
    }

    public LinkedList<Position<Character>> solve () {

        String s = "";

        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[4][4];


        String str = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                if(indexMap.get(matrix[i][j])!=null)
                {
                    ArrayList list = (ArrayList) indexMap.get(matrix[i][j]);
                    list.add(i+":"+j);
                    indexMap.put(matrix[i][j],list);
                }else if(matrix[i][j]!='-')
                {
                    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                    list.add(i+":"+j);
                    indexMap.put(matrix[i][j],list);
                }

            }



        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                findWordsUtil(matrix, visited, i, j, str);



        return list;
    }

    public static void main (String args []) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/dsolipa/Desktop/allWords.txt"));

        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            table.insert(line);
        }

        Boogle boogle = new Boogle(matrix);

        System.out.println(boogle.solve());

        //System.out.println(boogle.hasWord("or"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, the quadHastable just searches for str in the table, since aaron is there it basicly enters the IF with aaron as str. That said my issue is the row and column of the Position class getting overwritten. It should be creating a new position per iteration and the indexes are failing. Oddly enough the element is not...

Comment: Hi, A new position is created for each iteration, wherein the element is changing but i and j are not. So, all Position objects have the same row and column **(a(2,2) a(2,2) r(2,2) o(2,2) n(2,2))**. You should store the indices of characters and pass them while creating the instance. `Position<Character> pos = new Position<>(c, i of c in matrix, j of c in matrix`

Comment: @LockIt I have edited my answer and included the changes in Boogle Class to get the output a(0,0) a(1,0) r(1,1) o(1,2) n(2,2), let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: It works, but let me see if I got it. So you basicly put every position in a HashMap and then get them with an ArrayList to later pass them to the LinkedList ?

Comment: yes, I am storing positions of character in Hashmap with characters as the key. I used ArrayList since there can be more than one value for a character (as a(0,0) and a(1,0)) and the stored values will be used while creating Position object. You can further improve the code according to your requirements.

Comment: Ahh I see, I wondered how I was going to handle the multiple values! Thanks a lot mate! Cheers